# calculating percentage of data in one standard deviation in Java?

Tags: java

I want to calculate the max, min, mean, standard deviation and the percentage of data within one standard deviation from a file already existing in my directory using Java. As you can see below, I have found max, min, mean and stand deviation. How can I get the percentages of data within one standard deviation in the following code?

```
 int count = 1;
                int mean = 0;
                int sum = 0;
                int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                int mini = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                
                double std_deviation = 0;
                double squaresum=0;
                double computationalsum=0;
                int percentage;
                long lines = 0;
                Scanner file = null;
                int number=0;
                
                file_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the data file name:");
                
                try {
                 file = new Scanner (new FileInputStream (file_name));
                
                    }
                catch  (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("File not found");
                }
               max = file.nextInt();
               mini = max;
                while (file.hasNextInt()) {
                    number = file.nextInt();
                    
                    squaresum += Math.pow(number, 2);
                    computationalsum += number;
                    if (number > max) {
                        max = number;
                    }
                        else    if (number < mini)
                    {
                        mini = number;
                    }
                    sum += number;
                    count +=1;
                    
        
                }
                file.close();
                mean = sum/count;
                
              // use formula of standard deviation here
               double  sumofsquares = squaresum - ((Math.pow(computationalsum, 2)/(count-1)));
                double ssquared = sumofsquares/(count-1);
                double otherstdev = Math.sqrt(ssquared);
               double minrange = mean - otherstdev;
               double maxrange = mean + otherstdev;
                
             
                
//              calculate the percentage of mean in one stedv
//              while(scanner.hasNextInt()) { int = scanner.nextint() - mean / standard deviation;  if(int > -1 && int < 1) { then: this number is within 1 standard deviation (ie     oneDeviation++;}.......THEN you need to
//              take that counter and divide it by the total number of numbers in the file
//              }
//                for (int i =0; i=> min)
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println(mini);
                System.out.println(max);
        
                System.out.println(mean);
                                
               System.out.println(otherstdev);
//             System.out.println(newcount);
               

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exiting");
                done = true;
            }
        }
        while(!done);
          
  }

    
    
    }
```

Comment: It is first time to post question and the website keep rejecting my code. But, I assure you if you just help me on how to find the Percentage of data in one standard deviation in a code found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688703/14513619, I will get it, Please!

Comment: add your code between 3 ticks(\``` code here \```).

Comment: Aman, I was trying but it simply highlight the code with redlines. But, can you see the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688703/14513619 ? if you show me the direction to find the percentage of data in one standard of deviation in this code, I will get. Please, I need it. I spent the whole day but failed.

Comment: within one standard deviation of what? The mean? Well if you know the mean and the standard deviation then you can figure out the range you are interested in. so count how many values are in that range and divide by the total number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, by counting.

For example you have the following dataset:

```
Data value  Frequency
10          17
11          7
12          23
13          4
14          6
15          12
16          21
```

Using a calculator, you have found that the mean is about 13.06 and the standard deviation 2.24. That means that the range of one standard deviation is from 13.06+2.24 to 13.06-2.24 or 15.3 to 10.8.  You can simply count how many data points fall between these two lines.

So you must store the numbers in an array for example. And at the end you can iterate over the array and check the interval.

Comment: flaxel, if you look at the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688703/14513619 it works well, and it is not done by array. I just want to calculate the percentage of data in one standard deviation in this code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688703/14513619).

Comment: You need the numbers at the end. Otherwise you cannot calculate the percentage.

Comment: @Aba Stackoverflow isn't a service where people write code for you. Show us what you've done with a minimal reproducible example, and the specific error you are getting.